# Reroute existing wires with autorouter eagle

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

I created a board in Eagle, autorouted it and then moved components around. Is it possible to autoroute again, because now the wires are not straight. If I autoroute it just ignores existing wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the autorouter to re-route those signals, you have to "rip up" the traces you want re-routed. This tool is located near the bottom left of the tool bar on the left.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do a partial rip up, you need to manually rep up the traces. I believe you can type `ripup net` (where net is the name of the net you want to remove).

You can select a group of traces with the group tool and then select the rip up tool, right click on the group and select `Group: Rip Up...`. This will remove only the selected traces. So if you move an IC, you can group all the traces around that IC and rip them up.

If you need to rip up *all* of the traces and start over, you can do `ripup ;` to remove all traces from all nets.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all wires:

`RIPUP ;`

To delete a specific net, for example GND:

`RIPUP GND`